# In REST Assured can I able to log in using req username and password for HP-ALM?

Tags: rest-assured

Response response=given().that().parameter("j_username",userName).parameter("j_password", password).when().post("http://www.rest.com/qcbin/authentication-point/login.jsp?redirect-url=http%3A%2F%2Fx-pqrs12%3A1230%2Fqcbin%2Frest%2Fis-authenticated%3Flogin-form-required%3Dy").then().extract().response();

System.out.println(response.asString());

I want to login using this code. But I am getting HTML response and I am not able to login with this. Please help me out to get out of this problem.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Prat

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for form authentication?

```
given().auth().form("username", "password", new FormAuthConfig(..)). ..
```